# Error: Invalid combination of opcode and operands - nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, osdev

I am creating a small routine to load the `idtr` register with `lidt` instruction.
I have created this code -

```
global load_idt

load_idt:
    mov eax, esp
    add eax, 4
    lidt eax    ;<-----------------LINE 9
    ret
```

But when I compile this using Nasm, I get an error -

```
kernel/kernel_start.asm:9: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

My compilation command is-

```
nasm kernel/kernel_start.asm -f elf32 -o kernel/kernel_start.o
```

Can anyone point out the error in this program?

Comment: mnemonic is `LIDT m16&32` ... did you mean `lidt [eax]` ?

Comment: I want to call the function in C using `load_idt(<address-of-the-stored-idtr>)`.Do I have to use `[eax]`? Wouldn't it point to the value of idtr and not its address? @Tommylee2k

Answer (score 2):

The `idtr` register must be loaded with two pieces of information: the pointer to the table of descriptors and the size, in bytes minus one, of the former.

So, as [Tommylee2k pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630193/error-invalid-combination-of-opcode-and-operands-nasm#comment70460507_41630193), the only valid form is `LGDT m16&32`, where `m16&32` is a pointer to a memory location that holds a 16-bit size and a 32-bit base pointer.

Quoting Intel

> The source operand specifies a 6-byte **memory location** that contains the base address and the limit of the interrupt descriptor
>   table.

Beware that the size comes before the base address.

If I were you I'd keep the assembly minimal with a suitable use of C.
For example use a structure to represent the IDT base and limit, then pass it *by value* to a function written in assembly.
This also one the rarest case where [inline assembly is fine](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/i386/kernel/process.c?v=2.2.26#L315) so you may consider it.

```
/* IDT descriptor */
struct desc_t;

/* IDT */
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) IDT
{
   uint16_t size;
   struct desc_t* table;
};

/* Declaration of assembly function */
void set_idt(struct IDT idt);


;Parameters in order of push
;
;   struct IDT idt
;
_set_idt:
 lidt [esp+4]
 ret
```

---

**Trivia**

Technically `lidt eax` is encodable, it suffices to use a ModR/M byte with value 0d8h (011b for the *reg* field as an extended opcode, 11b and 000b for the *mod* and *r/m* fields to use `eax`) but `lidt` generates *#UD* if a register source is used (and infact `lidt eax` is reused for `vmrun` of AMD-v).

Comment: I do plan to call the assembly routine from C. Though I am using an array for the descriptor table not a pointer. Would this make any difference or some better functionality?

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing an IDT by value and not a single descriptor through set_idt? Possible I'm missing something in the translation or how that is suppose to be used.

Comment: Yes @MichaelPetch, I've written the wrong struct, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: If you meant to describe desc_t as an opaque type for the example (given the `struct desc_t;`) I think you might want to change `desc_t* table;` to `struct desc_t* table;`

Comment: @AneeshSharma An array is an optimal choice for the descriptor table. You still need an equivalent of the `struct IDT` of above as that's what `lidt` is expecting.